# What does this do in the React codebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I see the following in the React codebase:

```
export type TypeOfWork = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10;
```

What is it doing?

Source: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/shared/ReactTypeOfWork.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is flow or typescript syntax.

It defines a custom type which can only be a number from 0 to 10.

```
export type TypeOfWork = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10;
let x: TypeOfWork = 0;

x = 12; // <-- compiler would throw an error here
```

In this case an enum might be better (works only for typescript)

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html

```
export const enum TypeOfWork {
  IndeterminateComponent = 0, // Before we know whether it is functional or class
  FunctionalComponent = 1,
  ClassComponent = 2,
  HostRoot = 3, // Root of a host tree. Could be nested inside another node.
  HostPortal = 4, // A subtree. Could be an entry point to a different renderer.
  HostComponent = 5,
  HostText = 6,
  CoroutineComponent = 7,
  CoroutineHandlerPhase = 8,
  YieldComponent = 9,
  Fragment = 10
};
```

Which would be minified way better as you can see in the [compiled view](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20enum%20TypeOfWork%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20IndeterminateComponent%20%3D%200%2C%20%2F%2F%20Before%20we%20know%20whether%20it%20is%20functional%20or%20class%0D%0A%20%20FunctionalComponent%20%3D%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20ClassComponent%20%3D%202%2C%0D%0A%20%20HostRoot%20%3D%203%2C%20%2F%2F%20Root%20of%20a%20host%20tree.%20Could%20be%20nested%20inside%20another%20node.%0D%0A%20%20HostPortal%20%3D%204%2C%20%2F%2F%20A%20subtree.%20Could%20be%20an%20entry%20point%20to%20a%20different%20renderer.%0D%0A%20%20HostComponent%20%3D%205%2C%0D%0A%20%20HostText%20%3D%206%2C%0D%0A%20%20CoroutineComponent%20%3D%207%2C%0D%0A%20%20CoroutineHandlerPhase%20%3D%208%2C%0D%0A%20%20YieldComponent%20%3D%209%2C%0D%0A%20%20Fragment%20%3D%2010%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(TypeOfWork.IndeterminateComponent))